# django's ImageField from post raw data

Tags: python, django, http, python-2.7

I'm sending a raw data array (RGBA8888) from an application (in C++) to a django server in the http's post data encoded in base64 like:

```
field1=value1&prof_img=KSsf134SF38u483y... more bytes ....sdknADdSIU7rb==
```

I've already managed to decode it back from base64 to raw data, I've made some tests and the data gets converted correctly.

Now i'm stuck trying to do something with this decoded data so I can save it in a model's ImageField.

How could I save the image back to a .png file, or any other image file format? (I don't need alpha/transparency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save to disk the stream of bytes contained in the decoded base64 string. I got it working simply by just doing:

```
import base64

# assume 'x' is the variable where you have the base64 encoded image
# 'target.png' is the file name where you'll be saving it
# 'wb' is for a raw binary write operation
fout = open('target.png','wb')
# decode it and write it
fout.write(base64.b64decode(x))
# flush it
fout.flush()
```

Once you got it written in the disk, just add/edit the instance to the model in django with the file path.

That worked for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

```
from PIL import Image
img_size = (500, 500)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', img_size, raw_data)
img.save('mypic.png')
```

The rest will be Django job, right?

Comment: Throws: object has no attribute frombytes

Comment: Hmm is that old version of PIL? You can try fromstring() instead of frombytes()